# Get the Row count of the result of a Stored procedure in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm new to coldfusion. I'm executing "SP_REPORT" stored procedure and handling the result set in "result".
If result contains rows I'm displaying the data in table. I would like to handle the case when Stored procedure returns zero rows. If there are zero rows, I would like to display other table. How can I get the count of result. Thanks in advance

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="SP_REPORT" datasource="#DataBse#" >        
   <cfprocparam type = "In"     CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER"  value ='#Id#'   dbVarName = "@Id">
   <cfprocresult name="result">
</cfstoredproc>         
<table>
<cfloop query="result">
    <tr class="row#result.CurrentRow MOD 2#">
    <td align="left">#result.COMPANY_NAME#</td>
    <td align="left">#trim(result.FName)#</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
</table>
```

Comment: I solved the issue by using the below if condition
    <cfif result.recordcount GT 0 >

Comment: btw The `GT 0` part is redundant - a non-zero recordcount is already considered true.

Comment: `dbVarName` is a deprecated attribute on cfprocparam

Answer (score 2):

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="SP_REPORT" datasource="#DataBse#" >        
   <cfprocparam type = "In"     CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_INTEGER"  value ='#Id#'   dbVarName = "@Id">
   <cfprocresult name="result">
</cfstoredproc>         

<table>
<cfif result.RecordCount>
 <cfloop query="result">
  <tr class="row#result.CurrentRow MOD 2#">
   <td align="left">#result.COMPANY_NAME#</td>
   <td align="left">#trim(result.FName)#</td>
  </tr>
 </cfloop>
<cfelse>
 run another query
</cfif>
</table>
```